# can we set innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0 in phpMyAdmin. Is this database specific?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to change the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` value, can I do this on phpMyAdmin? Also can this value be set to a specific database or the entire server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a MySQL runtime configuration directive, it can be passed as a command-line argument when starting the MySQL server or by placing it in the MySQL configuration file. Neither of those are able to be affected by phpMyAdmin, though.

[According to the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode), the directive is global and set for the entire server instance, not per database.